# Creating Endpoints dynamically in Python

Tags: python, flask

I am Test Developer and I'm trying to create basic HTTP Server mock app which could generate  endpoints with using one "master endpoint" eg. /generate_endpoint.

I would provide url and body (and maybe  response code later) to /generate_endpoint, and when I call endpoint which I created it will give me the "body" response.

It must work without restarting server, since I would like to use it multiple times with different urls and body's.

Below is code I tried for that.

If that isn't possible to dynamically create endpoints, then maybe you could give me advice - because I want to create Mock to test MyApp and the basic workflow is like that:

1. Check if order exists (MyApp)
2. MyApp connects to externalApi and checks if order exists (That i want to mock)
3. MyApp returns value based on what is given in externalApi

but there is multiple responses (and multiple endpoints) which might occur and I want to have test cases for them all so I will not need external app for my tests.

here is what I tried:

```
from fastapi import HTTPException

router = APIRouter()
endpoints = {}


def generate_route(url: str, body: dict):
    async def route():
        return body

    router.get(path=url)(route)
    endpoints[url] = body


@router.post("/generate_endpoint")
async def generate_endpoint(endpoint_data: dict):
    endpoint_url = endpoint_data.get("url")
    endpoint_body = endpoint_data.get("body")
    if not endpoint_url or not endpoint_body:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="url and body required")

    generate_route(endpoint_url, endpoint_body)
    return {"message": f"route added for url {endpoint_url}"}
```

or

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class GenerateEndpoint(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("url", type=str)
        parser.add_argument("response", type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        def response():
            return args["response"]

        api.add_resource(response, args["url"])
        return {"status": "success", "url": args["url"]}, 201

api.add_resource(GenerateEndpoint, "/generate_endpoints")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

then im testing generate_endpoints with something like `{"url": "/someurl", "body": "something"}`
and then i Expect when i call GET 127.0.0.1:5000/someurl i will have "something" response

Comment: Have you considered using something like `json-server` which has been designed for the exact purpose of faking a service in an easy way? https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: I will check that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this variant:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, HTTPException


router = APIRouter()
endpoints = {}


@router.get("/{url:path}")
def get_response(url: str):
    if url in endpoints:
        return endpoints[url]
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Not Found")


def generate_route(url: str, body: dict):
    endpoints[url] = body


@router.post("/generate_endpoint")
async def generate_endpoint(endpoint_data: dict):
    endpoint_url = endpoint_data.get("url")
    endpoint_body = endpoint_data.get("body")
    if not endpoint_url or not endpoint_body:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="url and body required")

    generate_route(endpoint_url, endpoint_body)
    return {"message": f"route added for url {endpoint_url}"}


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

Comment: This doesnt work, when i send POST request to `127.0.0.1:5000/generate_endpoint` with
`{"url": "/someurl", "body": "something"}` and then GET request to `127.0.0.1:5000/someurl` im getting `{
    "detail": "Not Found"
}`and not "something"

Comment: How many uvicorn workers are you use? I've checked this via curl:
`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url": "asdf/asdf", "body": "body"}' http://localhost:5000/generate_endpoint` then `curl -X GET http://localhost:5000/asdf/asdf`

Comment: Ok thanks i must've confused something cause with your example and other examples it works, maybe it didnt cause I run uvicorn from console not from "main"

Comment: Could you run `echo $WEB_CONCURRENCY` [doc](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/)? You can run this example in any of this ways (`uvicorn --workers 1 --host localhost --port 8000 main:app`).